# Need a VBscript to reset wifi on my Vista PC

Tags: vbscript, windows-vista

Need a VBscript to reset wifi on my Vista PC

Comment: This is not place to make your demands.

Comment: If you have difficulty with English, please say so, otherwise it is unlikely that you will get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28VS.85%29.aspx) class. Unfortunately the `Reset` function in there is not implemented but there are [Disable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390364%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Enable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390385%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) methods and I'd assume that you'd achieve the same effect as a reset if you first disable it and then enable it again.

There's some sample vbscript code in the link for the `Enable` method.
You should hopefully be able to distinguish the wifi adapter on your machine by looking at the various properties of the `Win32_NetworkAdapter` class. However, be aware that I think some wifi adapters will lie about what `AdapterType` they are, so you might have to look at other properties than just that one.